# Sell 1/4 share or buy 3/4 share and leaseback?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-ownership

I currently own a 1/4 share of an Archer, but due to relocating I have put it up for sale and was planning to find another partnership once its sold. It's been on the market for about 3 months and have not had many people contact me with interest (no one serious). The other option I am debating is to buy up the other 3 shares and make the plane available for leaseback down in my new area.

Anyone have any feedback if leaseback is a good option? If I can get 80hrs/month (which is what the FBO owner says he's getting on each of his 172s), then I'd earn enough to cover the loan for buying the 3/4 shares, but I'm very concerned of hidden pitfalls. I've seen the condition of most rental planes & I'd be appalled if my Archer ever looked like those. Does anyone have any advice/suggestions?

Comment: The cost/benefit tradeoff with leasebacks is ***VERY*** complex - I don't think we can really advise you well in the Q&A format of the main site, but if you want to [stop by chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) it would be a good topic for a discussion.